# Can .php be an image extention?

Tags: website-design, file-format

I've recently made a new website and I'm using a template. See this image ([link](http://mirrorlessspecialist.com.au/wp-content/themes/paperpunch/images/sidebar/rotate.php)):

[image]

**The file extention is .php. Can anyone explain this?**

**NOTE:** When an image is posted here, stackexchange creates it's own location to store it. If you're right clicking and saving the pic in the question, you'll get a .jpg. But, [right click on the picture here](https://mirrorlessspecialist.com.au/).

Here are screenshots of what happens when I try to save it:

[image: Save as]

[image: rotate.php]

Comment: Were you able to get the .php and display it as an image, even when dowloaded? (the upload is indeed unrelated).

Comment: I don't know what you're asking... Try to save the image in the question now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A PHP script on the server (which is what the URL causes to be run) returns a response to the browser which contains the header

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

so the browser knows that what is returned is a JPEG image and displays it accordingly.

The browser uses the response headers to determine what to do with content. Client operating systems may behave differently — Windows, for example, has a heavy dependence on the filename extension. But if you attempt to save the image from the browser on a Windows system, you may find it's given a `.jpg` extension because the browser knows it's a JPEG image.

Comment: Thanks, that's a bit more help. But what would it take to explain why when I go to save the image, it saves it as _rotate.php_ rather than _sample-image.jpg_ ?? Source?

Comment: Depends on your browser. When I try and save it in Firefox on Windows, it suggests `rotate.php.jpg`. Answer updated.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m.

Comment: Well there you are. Chrome doesn't add an extension which Windows will understand correctly.

Comment: @bbking: in CMS (content management systems) which support templates, the actual image file names and locations may be stored in a database (sometimes even the data for the image is stored in the database as well). They do this so that the scripts for the site only need reference an abstract concept of "sidebar image." Your example, the abstraction is "rotate.php" which presumably looks up the image content and then passes it through to your browser.

Comment: As Andrew indicated, the php sends a response header saying "this is an image" it is also possible to include an information for the filename in which case the browser might show that instead of the script name, depending on how it is done.

Comment: I just tried it in IE and it saves it as _.jpg_ I had no idea about the difference between Chrome and IE. Thanks for your help! So it's just an image embedded in .php.

Answer (score 0):

It's still *encoded* like a "jpeg" or "png". A server can send back an image and say it's `Content-Type: text/html` with filename `image.php` and the browser will still render it as `png`. That's why saving it will attach the `.png` extension even though `image.php` didn't have it.

`.php` is not an image format, but, `.php` can return an image. It can be used to run some processing on the image and creating a compressed/smaller version depending on the size of the image requested.

Here's an explanation of how the browser handles images put in the `src` tag. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110673/9225733 for those who are interested.

Comment: its a 2013 question.. and it's not about **design** It's about scripting and functionality of web servers. You yourself linked to SO.. to explain functionality of server side scripting and web browsers.. that's *not* design.

Comment: That's a fair point and I agree that it's more technical than most questions here. Still, designers need to know the difference between `png`, `jpg` and `svg` so "what is a .php" is a valid question IMO. I answered 11y later since the answer is incomplete, I found an exceedingly rare case over here: https://www.takk.is/vara/pads-17-brunn/ which is not explained by the above answer.